# Package by feature but loose library dependencies?

Tags: domain-driven-design

So I'm reading about package by feature and domain-driven-design

- https://phauer.com/2020/package-by-feature/
- https://dzone.com/articles/package-by-layer-for-spring-projects-is-obsolete

What I'm curios about is how do you solve, or is there a way of solving to not tie down your main domain with heavy dependencies. I'll explain.

If you have all your feature related assets under one package, you will need to import the database library dependency on that subproject. Also if you're exposing this on an HTTP endpoint you might be introducing your HTTP dependency too.

```
com.myname.myservice.vehicle
|-Vehicle
|-VehicleService
|-VehicleRepository
|-VehicleQueries
```

So dependencies of `com.myname.myservice.vehicle` will be:

- HttpLibrary-1.0
- SQLLibrary-1.0

If you want to import this submodule's domain object `Vehicle` into another feature project Advertisements, you will drag both SQLLibrary-1.0 and HttpLibrary-1.0 with it. This way it's really difficult to develop Advertisements project losely coupled to Vehicles project because if one went too far ahead that would bring in binary incompatibilities.

Are there solutions for this. Am I not understanding package-by-feature or DDD correctly? Is this a pro-contra, it can't be solved? How do you deal with this in your projects?

FYI i'm using Scala, or you may note Java, but I think this applies to any language.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with most "package by feature" supporters is that **they aren't actually packaging by features, but by entities/aggregates**, leading to a huge dependency mess across so called "features".

This by "feature" structure...

```
/user
    UserController
    UserRepository
    User
    UserDto
/project
    ProjectController
    ProjectRepository
    Project
    ProjectDto
```

...is actually much worse than the following "by layer" architecture, because it only gives the illusion of decoupling, but in practice it's still a single Bounded Context (BC) and it's completely normal & expected that the model components living inside the same BC are coupled.

```
/domain
   User
   Project
   UserRepository
   ProjectRepository
/web
   UserController
   UserDto
   ProjectController
   ProjectDto
/infrastructure
   JdbcProjectRepository
   JpaUserRepository
```

The package by layer approach gives you several advantages, but most importantly it **allows you to isolate domain logic so that it's free of infrastructural concerns** & ideally remains pure, **making it highly testable, without mocking**.

You could theorically do the same with the above by "feature" structure, but it's much more difficult to maintain the isolation given all concerns are mixed together and it's also harder to leverage tools such as [ArchUnit](https://www.archunit.org/) to ensure the isolation.

My favorite approach is to package by Bounded Contexts -> Layers -> Aggregates and that's usually the kind of structure you find with popular DDD project samples:

[IDDD Samples](https://github.dev/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples)
[image]

[Modular Monolith Sample](https://github.com/kgrzybek/modular-monolith-with-ddd)
[image]

As a side note, a lot of people promoting micro-services are making the same mistake of having a service per entity/aggregate instead of segregating per Bounded Contexts, ending up with an even bigger mess...

Comment: Not an answer to my question. My question was pro-package-by-feature, I'm not asking advice on package-by-layer. However I think your lower examples are close to package-by-domain and that part looks good. I can't upvote or accept your answer but thank you.

Comment: @HunorKovács Well, the dependency problem you describe is a side-effect of package-by-feature, so I think the answer is relevant. If your domain was properly isolated it could be a seperate assembly that doesn't depend on an HTTP nor SQL library packages. That's exactly what packaging by layer & placing the domain at the center solves. By mixing up all concerns together you have to take the dependency hit, so it's a direct consequence of the package-by-feature architecture.